# Battery Charger and Load Current

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, battery-charging

I'd like to use this [Battery Charger](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf).

I need to charge a 4.2V Lipo battery and this charger IC can also power the system load simultaneously.

I've two questions.

This battery charger IC (from the OUT pin) powers an LDO which provides 3.3V to a microcontroller.
Is this voltage regulated? Like does it stay at a constant 4.2V at different load currents? I couldn't find information on the datasheet.

Also, is there a part where the battery also supplies the current to the load (while the input is applied) while looking into the function block diagram?

Please let me know.

Comment: There’s no mention of a regulator. It simply switches the battery voltage. If the battery voltage drops, so does the OUT pin. I cannot decode your second question. Please rephrase it.

Comment: Ok, just to clarify on the answer to my first question: If the input is 6V, battery's max voltage is 4.2V and the OUT pin provides 4.2V, the 4.2V wouldnt be regulated right? If the load draws more current, the voltage at OUT pin will also drop right?

Comment: On my second question, the battery is a separate pin. And the OUT pin, powers the system load. My question is, is there a leakage path (through the internal of the IC), where the current can flow from the Battery to the system load? Assuming the battery charger voltage is 4.2V and the system voltage is , say 4V? Can this scenario possibly happen? Or am I just confusing or misunderstanding too much?

Comment: What needs clarification? Look at the evidence. If in doubt, ask Microchip. If you need to make business decisions, why ask a third party?

Comment: The datasheet quantifies the leakage currents.

Comment: Why do you assume it even outputs 4.2V, especially if neither input or battery are not 4.2V?